# SVG: record the coordinates of an element for use with another element (without JS)

Tags: variables, svg, attributes, declare

I'm wondering if there is some way to define the value of position attributes for SVG elements so that they can be called in several objects.

For example, if I have two circles and want to draw a path from one circle to the other, I'd like be able to define the centres of the circles, and their radii, as variables. I'm completely new to working with SVGs, and have a beginner's level understanding of HTML, so I haven't even been able to figure out the correct language for searching for this (so even keywords would be appreciated).

For the sake of clarity, here is some pseudo-code for what I'd like to do:

```
<!-- Define Variables and Bind to Specific Values -->
< some-environment-for-declaring-&-binding-variables >
cx1="Ax"    
cy1="Ay"
r1="Ar"
          <!-- N.B. Ax/y/r and Bx/y/r represent numbers -->
cx2="Bx"
cy2="By"
r2="Br"
< /some-environment-for-declaring-&-binding-variables >

<svg>
   <!-- define the first circle using the variables declared, above -->
     <circ cx="cx1" cy="cy1" r="r1" stroke-width="2"/>
   
   <!-- define the second circle using the variables declared, above -->
     <circ cx="cx2" cy="cy2" r="r2" stroke-width="2"/>

   <!-- define a path that starts 2px to the right of the first circle and stops 2px away from the second circle. -->
     <path d="M calc(cx1+r1+2px), cy1 L calc(cx2-r2-2px), cy2" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

N.B. I'm pretty certain one can't call `calc` like I have for the `d` attribute; I've just put it there to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance for any pointers or suggestions, whatsoever.

Comment: For circles in modern browsers you can use CSS to position them and maybe CSS variables will meet your needs. For paths there's no such option though.

Comment: @RobertLongson so CSS will actually position the circle? or allows you to define variables whose value can be bound to the attributes? I'm finding the limitations on specifications for path points to be quite challenging (e.g. other shape elements can use % measurements, but not paths), which makes me feel like I'm missing some essential piece.

Comment: usually a viewBox will allow you to avoid percentages altogether.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't think that solves the broader issue: if I can define variables, I can modify the entire SVG by changing one value, as opposed to having to propagate that change throughout every other length that is affected by it (or am I missing something in your suggestion?).

Comment: That was my first suggestion, i.e. use CSS to position them and maybe CSS variables will meet your needs

Comment: @RobertLongson - I see, thanks; didn't realize you meant them, together. I don't have any real experience with CSS, so I'll have a look to see if it will work in my context. Thanks for your time and help!